# android - displaying progress dialog inside runOnUiThread in fragment

Tags: android

I have a simple android application that should display a progress dialog when I press 'activate' button. Basically, when I press 'activate', the app will display a progress dialog while detecting nearby sensors. I would like to update a progress dialog message as well while it detects sensors. The following code is implemented inside the fragment.

But my code does not display a progress dialog. I don't see anything when I press 'button'. It seems frozen.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {
    v.setEnabled(false);
    activateButton.setEnabled(true);
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pd.setTitle("Activating...");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();

            int count = 1;
            pd.setMessage("Detecting sensors...\n");
            while (true) {
                if (count >= 10) {
                    break;
                }
                count++;
                try {
                    pd.setMessage("Detected " + count + "=" + " sensor. \n");
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Based on the comment, I changed to this.

```
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setTitle("Activating...");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            int count = 1;
            pd.setMessage("Detecting sensors...\n");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                //
            }
            StringBuffer txt = new StringBuffer();
            txt.append(".....");
            while (true) {
                if (count >= 10) {
                    break;
                }
                count++;
                pd.setMessage("Detected " + count + "=" + " sensor. \n");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
                activateButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    };
    task.execute((Void[]) null);
```

But when this code runs, I get this error in this line (pd.setMessage("Detected " + count + "=" + " sensor. \n");).

Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

It would be helpful if somebody can point to where it goes wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You should not be calling Thread.sleep on the UI thread and you should consider using AsyncTask for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating view from background thread. From method 'doInBackground' you should call 'publishProgress' mehtod then update progress dialog in 'onProgressUpdate' (which will execute in UI thread). Check code below:

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
        public ProgressDialog mProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Progress", "Please Wait", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress("progress 1");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                publishProgress("progress 2");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            mProgress.setMessage(values[0]);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Change 'AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>' -> 'AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>'